# Where should I connect my clothes washer's discharge line to my plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, hose

I have just purchased my first property (in Australia) recently and have had few problems with the new washing machine that I ordered. The discharge hose from the washing machine wasn't installed properly and it was sort of placed along the sink next to it.

**Where should my discharge hose should go?** Apparently there isn't such hole for my discharge hose under the sink.

[image]

I have been told by the people who installed the washing machine that the discharge hose should be connected to the hose that I circled in red in the below picture.

[image]

However, (I don't know much about home repairs), but it seems unlikely that there is where the discharge hose should go as the hole from the discharge hose is too big for the tiny hole under the sink (circled red in the above picture)

[image]

Here is a closeup picture of the little hole under the sink. Another problem is that I also need to seal/close this small hole as it is leaking water when I use the sink or when the water is discharged from the washing machine **(any suggestion here on how to close this hole would be appreciated).** I placed a bucket underneath the little hole as a temporary fix.

[image]

So where should this discharge hose go? Any one with the expertise? Many thanks for the help. - Sarah.

Comment: That small inlet seems more like a dishwasher drain hose connection. The washing machine installation instructions (available likely from the manufacturer if you didn't get a copy with the machine) should have guidance.

Comment: Washing machines can cause a lot of water damage quickly from either the drain or the supply lines. I have been told to always use stainless-steel-braid jacketed supply lines, and to replace them every five years, to cut the chances of one leaking and causing a flood. Also, I'm pretty sure washing machines need an "air gap" or "high loop" on the drain line so dirty water/sewage cannot flow back into the machine. Certainly the hose end needs to be secured - otherwise it will flail around like a loose hose end once the stream of water starts shooting out.

Comment: If you haven't already, hold the drain hose or clamp it in place so it drains into that sink, run a laundry cycle, and make sure your sink drain can handle the large volume of water all at once that washers tend to produce. Your drain may need cleaning or reconfiguring to handle the flow. Congrats on being a homeowner!

Comment: Washing machine discharge (in the US at least) usually goes into a stand-pipe leaving an air gap between the hose & drain. Since you are Dutch, however, that may not be the case or expectation in the Netherlands. Bare in mind that many answers here will give you a US perspective that _may_ not be applicable to your situation. (It would help if you were to [edit] your locale into your question to make it more obvious.)

Comment: Does the end of the hose fit on the stub *above* the one circled in red?  Whichever stub you use, make sure you cap off the unused one!

Comment: @Huesmann No, that stub is not doing anything, it is sealed,  I actually don't know why it is there lol

Comment: @FreeMan Hi I live in Australia now :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I still don't know Aus plumbing, but I'm sure someone will. I'd venture to say that your particular set up is to allow you to plumb two different additional devices (clothes washer & dish washer, perhaps) into this one drain. Each of those little spouts comes with a "knockout" that you, literally, knock out to open it up. If you don't need one or both, you leave them in to ensure that your plumbing doesn't leak.

Comment: What is that little pipe with the bit of black hose attached under the sink?

Comment: Despite the "other side of the planet" aspect, the end of the hose lying on the sink suggests an inverted J bend, and that implies a standpipe.

Comment: @jay613 I have no idea, it doesn't seem to discharge anything when I turn on the tap

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with draining into the sink just as you are now.  It provides an air gap and a trap as required and it keeps the trap full if you don't use the sink much.

The only drawback is possible water staining in the sink.

But if you utilize the stubs under the sink, the high discharge rate from the machine might cause backflow into the sink anyway so you may gain *nothing*.  You will also then have to prevent backwash from the sink into the washer by using a high loop as for a dishwasher (look that up).

I would leave this alone.

You need to be sure that if the washer drains faster than the sink drain, the sink is big enough to buffer the difference.  And you need to do that no matter where the hose goes.

Answer (score 0):

The discharge hose will go in the red circle, where the plumber said to put it.

It is flexible hose so it can be slipped over the nipple made exactly for that purpose.

First use a hose clamp and slip it over the hose, now push the hose over the nipple, then tighten the hose clamp as close to the big pipe as you can.

The upper nipple and be use to provide air to the drain so the water can easily run off and not back up.

Answer (score 0):

For the leaking hole that's too small for the washer hose, there should be a threaded cap available at a hardware or plumbing supply store - take a picture, close-up, clear, focussed and with a ruler or tape measure held up to the port to improve your odds of getting the right thing at the store. You can also replace that whole section of trap, but that seems a bit more than should really be needed.